# java parentheses around class while storing reference to button

Tags: java, arrays, button, controls

i am in aprocess of learnning java.

i have this code from java reference:-

```
public class ButtonList extends Applet implements ActionListener {
String msg = "";
Button bList[] = new Button[3];
public void init() {
    Button yes = new Button("Yes");
    Button no = new Button("No");
    Button maybe = new Button("Undecided");
    // store references to buttons as added

    bList[0] = (Button) add(yes);  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here

    bList[1] = (Button) add(no);
    bList[2] = (Button) add(maybe);
    // register to receive action events
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        bList[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

and i wonder  what does  "(Button)  add(yes) "   stands for .

why should bList[]  be re assigned as a Button if its declared as Button on previous
paragraph.

Also what Button  whithin  parentheses  stands for here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Button) myVar` inserts a runtime check that `myvar` is assigned a `Button` so that the compiler can safely assume that `myVar`is a `Button`. If `myVar` is not a `Button` at runtime, an exception will be thrown.

Refer to Explicit casting for more information